# how to get generalized xpath for object in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
String str = "some value" ;

getTestBase().getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//h2[.='" + str + "']//parent::div//div[@id='sectionList'][1]/section/div/button")).click();
```

I need to put the above in loop so that [1] keeps increasing every time , how can I update the above xpath for the integer  ?

Comment: There are [several examples on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+xpath+loop) of looping with xpath expressions. Perhaps some of those can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "some value" ;
WebDriver driver = getTestBase().getDriver();
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h2[.='" + str 
    +"']//parent::div//div[@id='sectionList']["+i+"]/section/div/button")).click();
 }
```

This should solve your problem. 5 is just an arbitrary limit i assumed for writing the solution.

On the other hand you can try and get all the elements and store the elements in a list. Then parse the list to get the the buttons and click on them.

Some thing like:

```
String str = "some value" ;
WebDriver driver = getTestBase().getDriver();
List<WebElement> listOfButtons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h2[.='" + str + "']//parent::div//div[@id='sectionList']//section/div/button""));
for(WebElement el: listOfButtons){
    el.click();
}
```